# Projections for Iowa South are now inaccurate (EPSG, SpatialReference)

Tags: proj, epsg

Sometime in the last 30 days (maybe longer), the projections being provided on e.g. SpatialReference.org and EPSG.io are inaccurate for epsg:3418. (Iowa South) and maybe others?

- https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3418/proj4.txt
- https://epsg.io/3418-1696

As seen in this map from EPSG, the bounds appear to be way northeast from Iowa (up in Canada). This reflects what I'm seeing downstream, using https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php to convert GeoJSON values, which pulls from SpatialReference.

[image: Screenshot of Canada]

Does anyone know where I should be reporting this issue? Is it OSGeo/PROJ, or the Python library powering SpatialReference? I'm not super familiar with all of the fun Geo/projection terms, so I don't really know where to start.

Comment: looks like the changes where made on 10th January 2024 "Built on 2024-01-10 using PROJ 9.3.0" - would reach out to the devs https://spatialreference.org/about.html

Comment: Area of use is just informative so wrong extent does not need to be critical. Could you give an example of some coordinate transformation operation that gives wrong result nowadays?

Comment: @user30184 Here's an example of a coordinate in EPSG:3418:
`1623863.8131117225, 643763.90620113909`

The expected WGS84 is:
`lat: 41.766901, lng: -93.560676`

But today's result is:
`lat: 44.960581, lng: -79.222403`

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz - added an issue here to see if it gets in front of the right person: https://github.com/OSGeo/spatialreference.org/issues/12

Comment: With Proj 9.3.1 I get from `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:3418 -t_srs epsg:4326` values `-93.5606745002133 (lon) 41.7669002221578  (lat)`.

Comment: I can't repeat your result today with `https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3418&t_srs=4326&x=1623863.8131117&y=643763.9062011` The area of use on the map is not right, though.

Comment: Update: it was indeed a bug in the PHP implementation (or at least it was solved with a fix in the PHP implementation). https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php/pull/140 This is working again for me now! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: It was related to the PHP implementation https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php/pull/140

I'm unsure whether it was a bug introduced in the library, or a change in the data upstream. Regardless, the latest version works now.